# Vim set highlight for specific sections of code

Tags: vim

Using smarty's tag {block} as an extension of a template, we got sections of code that's it's not  highlighted, I think is something related of the context and how vim decides what to highlight according to that,

So the question is, there is a way to tell vim to highlight a section of code with a specific color-schema?

Here is what I mean

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Questions about programming tools (including editors and IDEs) are best suited for Stack Overflow. I'm moving this question there for you now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
syn include     @HTML syntax/html.vim
syn region      htmlSnip start="{block" end="{/block}" contains=@HTML
```